# What are grid output devices and bitmap output devices for the grid media feature?

Tags: css, media-queries

What are grid output devices and bitmap output devices for the grid media feature?

Comment: (comments removed; off-topic and unhelpful)

Comment: As a summary of the comments, this question probably could do with clarification.

Answer (score 5):

From the "[Internet Encyclopedia](http://books.google.com/books?id=bW2_KaeKuVkC&lpg=PA154&ots=TWn4Py8x70&dq=emboss%20computer%20media&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q=grid&f=false)":

> "Grid media consists of a grid or array of discrete characters.
>   Examples include traditional computer terminals and character
>   printers"

Grid and Bitmap also appear to be supersets of other media types and are counter to each other:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/media.html#media-groups

So a "grid" media query would match any of the following:

1. terminal
2. braille device
3. handheld with limited display (perhaps older solution for the visually impaired)